# JavaScript CSS Selector, Select with id

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors, selectors-api

I'm trying to get the element using `document.querySelectorAll()` method.

```
var elementList = Firebug.browser.document.querySelectorAll("DIV[id='hplogo']");
```

when I use this with Google web site, this function returns an array with 44 elements. Please give me a solution...

Comment: Is jQuery available to you? It makes it much easier.

Comment: I'm trying to do this without jQuery...

Comment: Right. Then `document.getElementById('hplogo');` is the way to go.

Comment: @bytec0de: jQuery doesn't make this easier.

Comment: *"when I use this with Google web site, this function returns an array with 44 elements"* No it doesn't, it gives you a syntax error.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder In which way doesen't it make it easier?

Comment: @bytec0de: In what way *does* it? I have nothing against jQuery and use it every day. But it doesn't make *this* any easier.

Comment: @bytec0de — In all ways.

Comment: Relax guys, *easy* is a subjective term. @T.J.Crowder is right about the syntax error though

Answer (score 3):

`document.querySelectorAll` will return all elements on the page that match your query, hence why you're seeing 44 different elements.

Use `document.getElementById('hplogo')` instead of querySelectorAll to get the one element with the ID that you're looking for.

Comment: That's assuming valid HTML where there is only one element with the ID on the page

Comment: That is correct. From what I can tell the OP is looking for one specific div with the id of 'hplogo'. For this use case, `getElementById` seems appropriate.

Comment: Agreed. Seems that is the objective. Worth highlighting to the OP that their HTML *should not* contain duplicate IDs though

Comment: "document.querySelectorAll will return all elements on the page that match your query" 
I understand you.. But id is unique. how can it match with multiple elements?

Comment: @Pasindu: Clearly the `id` is *not* unique. They should be, they're *required* to be, but if the author of the HTML breaks that rule, the browser doesn't just ignore the `id`s. They're still there. And `querySelectorAll` will do what it's supposed to do: Return a list of all of the matching elements. This is assuming that you have actually formed the selector correctly, which is unclear, as your question has a syntax error that prevents the code from running at all, and thus is clearly not what you're actually using. For all we know, what you're *actually* using doesn't use the `id` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
Firebug.browser.document.querySelectorAll("DIV#hplogo]");
```

please try this.

btw what is hplogo? is it a variable or is it a selector?

Comment: Please do not put follow-up questions into an answer. Once you have enough rep, you should put those into a comment.